# wordpress: default location of header.php and footer.php

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

Here's a really simple question. I have wordpress 3.4.2 installed. I'm trying to build a theme from scratch. So I've added a style.css file and an index.php file. Both only containing the bare minimum. Now I'm wondering when I call the get_header() and get_footer() functions from index.php, where are the header.php and footer.php files located that wordpress is using to generate the header and footer of my site?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the answer here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header. It seems the default header.php and some other template files are in wp-includes/theme-compat/

Answer (score 9):

In the root folder of your wordpress theme e.g. wp-content/themes/mytheme so you will have to create these also ...

Comment: eventually I will off course. But if I don't create them in my theme folder wordpress still generates a header and a footer when I call get_header() or get_footer(). Just wondering where it gets the defaults from.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your question